# Website header logo image is not sharp

Tags: html, css, image, magento

My company website has the company logo on the header. But for some reason the logo is not sharp enough. I have tried several different resolution and DPI as well. But the logo image is not coming out to be sharp enough.

but if you scroll down a bit, and see the logo on the stationary menu on the top, the logo is pretty sharp.

[site](http://biocarve.com/)

Recently I was trying to have a popup on the website, with the same logo, again the logo is not clear on it.

Please help me out with this.

Comment: i think the best way is to use an SVG

Comment: since [it looks the same outside of the page](http://www.biocarve.com/skin/frontend/biotheme/default/bc/images/logo.png), that's probably because the resample method used to reduce the picture at photoshop (nearest neighbor, bilinear, bicubic, bicubic smoother, bicubic sharper, bicubic automatic). It means this question belongs to [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @freestock.tk I have tried several ways to fix it via design. the logo itself has been created via a vector. It's something to do with the code or the framework. That's the reason I have this question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perfect solution is to convert your image to a vector form like SVG.
by using an SVG file you'll reduce the file's size and remain high quality/resolution.

Give it a shout, I've encountered this myself ;)

Comment: I have created the jpg via a vector itself. SVG can not be used in html... can it ?

Comment: yes it can be used, you can either add its location like a normal image, src="path/logo.svg" or you can delete the <img --- /> tag and add the svg code of the vector file, to get the code right click the image and open it with a code editor, then copy it and paste it instead of the image, but i recommend you try the first option :)